# UIImagePicker disable camera zooming

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I add overlay with UIGestures atop of the UIImagePicker camera view and I need to disable camera zooming because it fires when I zoom in or out the overlay with pinch especially when user zoom out overlay image too much. I can't find information how to prevent this behaviour. If it's not possible for UIImagePicker, do I need to switch to AVCaptureSession?

Comment: I have the same question, I add a scalable/rotatable view as cameraoverlay. I want to disable the camera zooming also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figure it out finally by using [ImagePickerController.view addSubView:myOverlayView] instead of ImagePickerController.overlayView = myoverlayView. Hope this help u.